# css configuration in webpack not detecting class styles but detects element styles (not css modules)

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, build

My first using webpack and I can`t resolve it, help please!

If I add style in my css file like:

```
div {
 background:red;
 }
```

it works, but if I add style to class:

```
.container {
 background:red;
 }
```

styles not working...
I found same theme https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.f89b6a0d-63bed1e2-167cf029-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/54593484/css-configuration-in-webpack-not-detecting-class-styles-but-detects-element-styl
but I dont use css modules.
My webpack.conf:

```
const ieConfThree = {
    entry: {
        arm: path.resolve(__dirname, 'IE/index.js'),
    },
    target: ['web', 'es5'],
output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].ie.bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'ISU/dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
},

module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.html$/i, loader: 'html-loader' },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'IE')],
    
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            [
                                '@babel/preset-env',
                            ],
                        ],
                    },
                },
            ],
        },

        {
            test: /\.s?css$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    options: {
                        publicPath: './',
                    },
                },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                    },
                },
                {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                },
            ],
        },

        {
            test: /\.ico|\.png|\.gif|\.svg|\.jpg($|\?)/,
            generator: {
                filename: 'images/[name][ext][query]',
            },
            type: 'asset/resource',
        },
    ],
},

plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'АС ИСУ',
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'IE/ieMock.html'),
        filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'ISU/IENotSupport.html'),
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '[name].[contenthash].css' }),
],

};

    module.exports = [ieConfThree];
```

My html and css files before build:

```css
.ie-support-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    background: #00A698;
    border: black;
}

.ie-support-container__el {
   padding: 40px;
    background: #00A698;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" lang="en">
<base href="/">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<main>

<div class="ie-support-container">
    <div class="ie-support-container__el">
        <h1>
           Internet Explorer
        </h1>
        <p>
           !!!!
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="ie-support-container__el">
    <div class="browser_label">
        <img src='./images/Browser.svg' />
        <span>Browse</span>
    </div>
    <div class="browser_label">
        <img src='./images/Browser.svg' />
        <span>Browse2</span>
    </div>

</div>
</div>

</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Can not found answer. Where is mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference your CSS file from somewhere in your code so webpack knows it's being used. For example in your index.js file you can `import` it like so:

```
import "./path/to/your.css";
```

Generally, when debugging webpack issues it's helpful to

1. Check (and state) what webpack version you are using. Big differences between v4 and v5
2. Look at (show us) the webpack output
3. Specifically here: Did webpack generate a CSS file?
4. Is the CSS file being referenced by the generated HTML file?
5. Look at content of the generated CSS file

Sometimes it's easier to debug issues in webpack production mode: add `mode: "production",` to your webpack.conf